# One to many sequelizejs ORM failed to get result

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have two model one is `Order` and next is `OrderItem` with a one to many relation ie one order have more one order Items available.

I want to get each order with all orderItems of that order

1)`Order PK:id`

2)`OrderItem FK:order_id Refers id in Order`

Here is my relation

```
Order.hasMany(OrderItem, { as: 'orders',targetKey:'order_id' } );
        OrderItem.hasOne(Order,{foreignKey:'id'});
        sequelize.sync();



Order.findAll({where:{artist_id:req.user.id}}).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
})
```

But the `result` doesn't contains the orderItems

Comment: you should define belongsto relation instead of hasone `OrderItem.belongsTo(Order,{foreignKey:'id'});`

Answer (score 0):

The `hasOne`puts the id on the destiny model, this mean that you'll generate a foreign key on Order. Only need to use `hasMany`like this: `Order.hasMany(OrderItem, { as: 'orders');`. Doing this you will have a foreign key of Order on OrderItem.

Then on your query if you need the order and the items you have to use the include clause: `

```
Order.findAll({
    where:{
        artist_id:req.user.id
    },
    include: [{
      model: OrderItem,
      as: 'orders'
    }]
}).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
})
```

Remenber to use `as`, this will tell sequelize with relation are you refering if you have more than one on the same model.